# Add an action button in the top of a tree view

Tags: vscode-extensions

Is it possible to add an action button on the top of a custom tree view with vscode API ?
A button like the "Commit" button in source control. ([image: Image of this button])

I tried with a [viewWelcome](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.viewsWelcome), but I can't show the tree below.
I tried with [TreeView#message](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeView) but it don't allow Markdown so the button don't show up.